# How to use regex in order to catch a power statement

Tags: c#, regex, math, expression

How can I use regex to catch a power statement, here are some examples:

2<sup>4</sup>

(2*5)<sup>x</sup>

y<sup>(y+1)</sup>

or more complex ones such as x<sup>4</sup>+(x*2)<sup>(x+1)</sup> in which case it has 2 matches ("x<sup>4</sup>" and "(x*2)<sup>(x+1)</sup>")

I managed to get it working without the parenthesis using the expression:

```
Regex rPower = new Regex(@"\w\^\w");
```

But to deal with the possible existence of parenthesis I was thinking of something along these lines, but it still isn't working...

```
Regex rPower = new Regex(@"(?(?=\()(.*?(?=\)))|(\w))\^(?(?=\()(.*?(?=\)))|(\w))");
```

Any help/explanation that includes the thought process behind it would be deeply appreciated since I don't know much about regex and and I'm just now starting to learn it.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: For clarity what I intend to do is:

If in the string there is a substring which may start with an "(" in which case it should read everything from that "(" until it find and ")" otherwise assume it's an "\w", separated by a "^" which in turn follows another pattern just like the one it started with.

Basically it will match the expression "(random_Expression)<sup>(random_Expression)</sup>", but it may not actually be a complex expression, if it does not contain any parenthesis I will assume it's a simple "\w".

I hope I made myself clear :S

Comment: Can you define exactly what a power statement is? Is `((((((((((2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2) ^ 2` a power statement?

Comment: A power statement would be B^E, B being the base and E the exponent. B and E could be complex expressions themselves and in turn be powers as well, I'll edit the post to try and provide more clarity.

Comment: "_it may not actually be a complex expression_". Can you define exactly what a complex expression is?

Comment: But no, those would be multiple power statements within each other except for the lonely "(2)" which for my purposes is not, although it technically is 2^1.

Comment: By complex expression I mean any characters found between the "(" and ")", it could be any mathematical expression.

Comment: I think it will be difficult to validate with Regex when `identifiers` come into picture. consider you have int x = 10; how to evaluate this`abc^2`. this is true or false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this:

`(\([^)]*\)|\w)\^(\([^)]*\)|\w)`

Sample matches:

```
2^2 matches 2^2
a+b^c matches b^c
(a+b)^(c+d) matches (a+b)^(c+d)
2^(a+b) matches 2^(a+b)
(a+b)^2 matches (a+b)^2
(a+b)^2+5^2-(3+2)^(2+3) matches (a+b)^2, 5^2, (3+2)^(2+3)
```

Obviously, you may find bugs on the expression if stuff like nested operations is used. If you are going to work with complex expressions, I guess you will have to parse them carefully with a more elaborated method.

> Could you please edit or reply with an explanation even if brief of
>   how the expression is working?

It is similar to your original expression `\w\^\w`, but it changes each `\w` with `(\([^)]*\)|\w)`. If you look closely, that matches either "something inside parentheses" (given by`\([^)]*\)`, which doesn't work for nested brackets) or "a simple word" (`\w`).

Hope that helps a bit :)

Comment: It works! If it's not too much to ask, could you please edit or reply with an explanation even if brief of how the expression is working? I'm interested in understanding it a bit more :) Thank you very much.